# Usage of the English language in judgements

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis

Having read judgements, again and again, I keep stumbling upon this construction which really irritates me, as I do not understand how people so well-educated can use the verb *find* in its wrong form.

> Is it sufficient to found a conviction of murder?

Wouldn't it be better to say:

> Is it sufficient to **find** a conviction of murder?

Comment: [To found](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/found) is a verb that means in this context *to establish the bases for*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks sufficient context.

Comment: What is "it"? Please provide complete context for (what I assume is) the quote.

Comment: [Found](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/found) (verb)

Comment: The question(hoping it adds sufficient context for some) is: is the verb found used correctly in that sentence 'Is it sufficient to found a conviction of murder'?

Comment: **EDIT YOUR QUESTION AND ADD A PARAGRAPH OR TWO OF CONTEXT**, if you do not want to see the question closed.

Comment: @Ana Welcome to EL&U. I hope you get your answer. But if not, could you please tell us what research have you attempted on your own?
And I encourage you to take the site [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: @Graffito When it's used in that sense, it's usually followed by _on_, e.g. _the conviction was founded on insufficient evidence_

Comment: @ Graffito Thanks, now it makes sense :) And weirdly enough you did not need MORE context.

Comment: @Ana But what if the answer wasn't correct? More context is needed to avoid mistake. and I am sure you understand that.

Comment: Here is an example from [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/found): She ​left a ​large ​sum of ​money in her will to found a ​wildlife ​sanctuary.

Comment: @haha I agree with you, but for me, it makes sense in that context. And I think it is correctly used in both situations. Also, I have no idea how much more context you need. That is the phrase that, in my head, needed correcting. It is from the beginning of a judgement which sounds like this: 'It was sufficient to found a conviction for murder for a secondary party to a killing in the course of a joint enterprise.'

Comment: Just a heads-up. You already received 4 close-votes and the reasons are stated in the above comments. Please note that we don't encourage a question just for yourself, we encourage a question which is useful for other users and future readers.

Answer (score 3):

I think the confusion is the use of found as the [*past participle of find*](https://www.google.com/search?q=found%20definition), and [*found*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/found) in terms of

> to set up or establish on a firm basis or for enduring existence

and

> to provide a basis or ground for

Think of *foundation*, which also comes up in a legal context.  *Find* in a legal context can specifically refer to a [*finding*](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/finding), which is

> The result of the deliberations of a jury or a court.

In the law, these specific statements carry some additional burdens than they do in normal speech.